# LINQ to XML - accessing descendants with a prefix

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a sample xml file like this

```
<vs:BioData>
<vs:Name>Name</vs:Name>
<vs:Address>address</vs:Address>
<vs:Zip>Zip</vs:zip>
</vs:BioData>
```

All the nodes have a prefix value as vs and can anyone tell me how would I go about parsing this file to read Name and Address Information? I am very new to LINQ. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to know what the namespace is. That will have been declared earlier, with something like:

```
xmlns:vs="http://some_url_here"
```

You can query using `XNamespace`:

```
XNamespace vs = "http://some_url_here";
var names = doc.Descendants(vs + "Name")
               .Select(x => (string) x)
               .ToList();
```

The `+` here is actually converting an `XNamespace` and a string to an `XName`.

Comment: BUT if one needs to retrieve attribute of an element, retrieve element with nameapce and should not apply the namespace for attribute!

Comment: @HydTechie: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. (In particular, it's about attributes and those aren't mentioned in the question...)

Comment: i have searched for questions around how to retrieve attribute, I was unfortunate. for an element this smart technology demands namespace but not for attribute..i found this by trial, Jon! so I felt, lot of folks will not stop at element finding like in  great tech talks via simple hello world, earn lumps of money. If you shower some love towards tech community, this comment is not totally away from the context. with respect to your humble contributions, HydTechie __/\__

Comment: @HydTechie: No, the comment *is* irrelevant to this particular question. There are *lots* of questions about retrieving attributes in LINQ to XML (search for "linq to xml attribute" here and you'll see lots), and even if there weren't the correct solution is to ask a question, not add a comment on an unrelated question. If you're asking about namespaces and attributes specifically, then there may be fewer questions, but again, the answer is to ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

The prefix "vs" should be mapped to a namespace in the header of the XML document, eg:

```
<FooDocument xmlns:vs="http://schemas.example.com/vs">
```

Then you can select those elements with LINQ by using an XNamespace, like this:

```
XNamespace vs = "http://schemas.example.com/vs";

var names = myXDoc.Root.Descendants(vs + "Name");
```

The XNamespace and XName types all support implicit conversion from strings.

Comment: Lawrence Wenham Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is really old but wanted to provide some additional information.  I was directed to this question and answer while seeking help with a more complex xml file.  My xml had several names spaces and had nested namespaces as well.  I was able to solve my problem with the suggestions found at this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2fe1d2a-48f9-4620-80ed-92f04b48020d/how-to-parse-an-xml-document-using-multiple-name-spaces?forum=xmlandnetfx)

It was great help and wanted to post it here in case someone else ran into the same problem