# XPath get first child comment only before any other elements

Tags: xml, dom, xpath

Using XPath, I want to get those comments which are the first children of `item` elements, before any other element children.

I have XML like this:

```
<list>
    ...
    <item id="52">
        <!-- this is optional comment, need get this -->
        <randomParam>asd</randomParam> <!-- not this comment -->
        <anotherRandomParam type="3" />
        <paramText /> <!-- not this comment -->
        ...
    </item>
    <item id="53">
        <param1>test</param1> <!-- not need this comment -->
        <param2 title="text">text</param2>
        <someParam>
        <!-- not need this comment -->
                <test />
                <test /> 
                <test />
        </someParam>
        ...
    </item>
    ...
</list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//item/comment()[not(preceding-sibling::*)]
```

will select all `comment()` children of `item` elements that have no preceding element siblings,

```
<!-- this is optional comment, need get this -->
```

as requested.

Comment: i try in XPath online and get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'childPosition' of undefined`, element() its not xpath function?

Comment: I'll venture to guess you've gotten that result on [xpather.com](http://xpather.com/), which is [known to fail to implement the XPath standard faithfully.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215146/290085)... ...confirmed.  Avoid xpather.com -- it's non-compliant with the XPath standard.  If you use a compliant XPath site or library, you'll find that the above XPath works perfectly well.

Comment: Yes, but in PHP(which use libxml) i got warning: `DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression [...][...]`, i think need replace `element()` to `*`, or `node()` can be used too under option `preserveWhiteSpace=false`

Comment: @PlayerKillerYKT:  `element()` requires XPath 2.0, and libxml only supports XPath 1.0.  Yes, you can use `*` so that the above XPath will work with XPath 1.0 and up.  Answer updated.  This still doesn't absolve xpather.com, which still fails with `*`.

Comment: Сan you answer pls, if there may be several comments before other elements, how i can get multiple? Like this: `<item><!-- comment get this --><!-- other comment and get this --><param>test</param><param2 /></item>`.

Comment: The XPath in the answer would select both of those comments already.  Be sure to be using a library call that can return multiple results, not just select the first one.